# Merge sql throws Unique constraint violation error

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, unique-constraint

I have below two table for which when i query table `TEST_RUA`:

```
select  CLASS, ID_LL, ID_UU, TKR from TEST_RUA   where ID_UU= 'GV9999B12M0'
```

it returns:

```
CLASS    ID_LL   ID_UU          TKR
Bond    (null)  GV9999B12M0     WIB
```

When i query table `TEST_RUA_MER`:

```
select CLASS, ID_LL, ID_UU, TKR from TEST_RUA_MER   where ID_UU= 'GV9999B12M0'
```

it returns:

```
CLASS    ID_LL   ID_UU          TKR
Bond    (null)  GV9999B12M0     WIB
```

You can see both the values are same for table where `ID_UU= 'GV9999B12M0'`. The table `TEST_RUA_MER` has unique index on columns `ID_LL, ID_UU, TKR`.

Now i have below merge query which throws error as `ORA-00001: unique constraint violated` and i dont understand how can i avoid this error as both the table values are same then in this case this merge query should try to update and not to insert in table `TEST_RUA_MER` .

```
merge into TEST_RUA_MER h   using  (    
select distinct r.CLASS, r.ID_LL, r.ID_UU, r.TKR from TEST_RUA r   ) s 
on (s.ID_LL=h.ID_LL and s.ID_UU=h.ID_UU  and s.TKR=h.TKR) when matched then   
update set h.CLASS = s.CLASS, h.ID_LL = s.ID_LL, h.ID_UU = s.ID_UU, h.TKR = s.TKR
when not matched then   insert values (s.CLASS, s.ID_LL, s.ID_UU, s.TKR);
```

Comment: i have corrected the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `NULL` causes problems; it isn't "equal" to anything, so this:

```
on (s.ID_LL=h.ID_LL
```

fails.

Try with

```
on (nvl(s.ID_LL, -1) = nvl(h.ID_LL, -1)
```

(depending on what `ID_LL` column's datatype is; I presumed it is a number).

Comment: ID_LL, ID_UU, TKR  datatype is varchar2

Comment: OK, so instead of -1 use some character.

Comment: i dont know how but with -1 also its working but will i create problem later on ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, As mentioned in the other answer also, cause of the error is `s.ID_LL=h.ID_LL`. You can update it as

```
( s.ID_LL=h.ID_LL OR (s.ID_LL is null and h.ID_LL is null) )
```

OR

```
( s.ID_LL=h.ID_LL OR coalesce(s.ID_LL, h.ID_LL) is null )
```

Comment: now i am facing performance issue ...i tried both sql and my merge query is taking more than 20 minutes and its still running..without this condition it runs within few seconds...i have 800000 rows in my table TEST_RUA_MER...i tried to remove index on this table and still merge query is taking too much time ..

Comment: can i create may be functional index here ?